# MS5611 (barometer / thermometer) returns temperature going up if checked repeatedly

Tags: microcontroller, sensor

I have a ms5611 module working fine.  It reads pressure and temperature without a problem.  However I have one condition I have a problem with.

I am calculating out the current altitude using the pressure and temperature, but if I check temperature too quickly and repeatedly, the value goes up like below.

```
21.66
21.66
21.67
21.67
21.68
21.68
21.68
21.68
21.69
21.69
21.69
21.68
21.69
21.69
```

*I did a loop sleeping 0.1 second above.
*It keeps going up if I don't stop the loop.

I am pretty much sure it is because the module sensor itself is heated up by the calculations, but how often should I check on the values so that the values won't be affected the heat from itself?

Is there a way to read the datasheet for this?
http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7FMS5611-01BA03%7FB%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_MS5611-01BA03_B.pdf%7FCAT-BLPS0036

Comment: Must be from self-heating during conversion of 3mW and say 33'C/W thermal resistance implies it will rise 1'C if left to convert continuously.  Here is only rises 30 milli centrigrade over a short period.

Comment: looks like 2-3 times a second is your limit. you might be able to heatsink it for faster updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is self heating.

Experiment is the answer. Try different periods and plot the result.

As a rule you should not believe that a sensor chip works properly because the manufacturer claims so, not should you assume that because it worked for someone else, you are actually using it right.

Look at the graphs for the [ADM1034](https://www.i2cchip.com/pdfs/TemperatureSensor_ADM1034.pdf), and the conclusion (sec 6.5) for an example of this.